# How do I install things on Kitematic Boot2docker linux?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, docker, .net-core

I have run through the boot2docker virtual machine setup tutorial in the docker toolbox https://www.docker.com/toolbox.

Using window 10 as my base, I managed to get virtualbox running from kitematic with `Linux default 4.0.9-boot2docker`

When I start trying to run `apt-get` or `yum` to install things like NODE.JS or ASPNET I'm told that the files aren't found.

The end goal is to be able to run my aspnet docker images on my local environment.

Do I need to install aspnet, node, etc... on my docker server before I can start running aspnet docker images?  If yes, how do I install them in the version of linux that has no apt-get or yum?

edit - note it is the ASPNET core documentation that seems to suggest I need to install things on the docker server. https://dotnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/installing-core-linux.html perhaps I can docker-build within the windows environment and docker-run from the linux VM without actually installing anything other than my docker image?

Comment: So for node.js, why not pull the image `node` directly, same as `aspnet`. You needn't start from beginning to install these applications step by step.

Comment: thanks for the comment! I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand how one would pull an image directly. Did you learn from a different tutorial? Perhaps you could link it?

Comment: try `docker pull node` and `docker pull microsoft/aspnet` first. The image is pulled from `hub.docker.com`. If you need more, please go through docker documents.

Comment: Thanks again BMW! That appears to be working. If you wanted to write that as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With docker you can focus on using application, not installation.

you needn't waste time on application installation that you can pull the image directly to get `node.js` or `aspnet` environments work in minutes.

So answer your question, you can have these environments ready via pull command:

```
docker pull node
docker pull microsoft/aspnet
```